# Why calling IBM DB2 SELECT Stored Procedure with large amount of data is very slow?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw

We started to experience problem with the SELECT stored procedure since the new  requirement came in – the application should be able to handle large amounts of data, i.e., 1-3 millions of rows that satisfy search criteria. We have a table TRANSACTION with million of rows that have COMPANY_ID = 52360839 and TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'L'. We want to get 500 rows with the latest TRANSACTION_STAMP date, so we need to ORDER BY TRANSACTION_STAMP DESC. First of all, we have added an index to TRANSACTION table to make SELECT statement run faster:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX XTRANSACTION_03 ON TRANSACTION (
    COMPANY_ID, TRANSACTION_STATUS, TRANSACTION_STAMP DESC);
```

The security requirement of the project is to apply stored procedures. The procedure looks as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE READ_TRANSACTIONS(
  IN  in_COMPANY_ID         DEC(13, 0),
  IN  in_TRANSACTION_STATUS CHAR(1),
  IN  in_TRANSACTION_LIMIT  INTEGER,
  OUT out_sql_state         CHAR(5),
  OUT out_sql_code          INTEGER,
  OUT out_failure           CHAR(5))
LANGUAGE SQL
READS SQL DATA
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN
  DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR (5) DEFAULT '00000';

  DECLARE TRANSACTION_LIST CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM TRANSACTION
    WHERE COMPANY_ID = in_COMPANY_ID AND 
        TRANSACTION_STATUS = in_TRANSACTION_STATUS
    ORDER BY TRANSACTION_STAMP DESC
    LIMIT in_TRANSACTION_LIMIT;

  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN
    SELECT SQLSTATE, SQLCODE
    INTO out_sql_state, out_sql_code
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
    SET out_failure = '00001';
  END;

  SET out_sql_code = 0;
  SET out_sql_state = '00000';
  SET out_failure = '00000';

  OPEN TRANSACTION_LIST;
END
```

To test it, I have created a table for persisting outputs:

```
CREATE TABLE Z_OUTPUTS(
    TRANSACTION_ID INTEGER,
    Sql_Code INTEGER,
    Sql_State CHAR(5),
    Select_Failure CHAR(5),
    Creation_Stamp TIMESTAMP
);
```

And we need an SQL block to call the procedure:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE out_sql_state CHAR(5) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE out_sql_code INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE out_failure CHAR(5) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE transaction_id INTEGER;
    DECLARE result RESULT_SET_LOCATOR VARYING;

    CALL READ_TRANSACTIONS(52360839, 'L', 500, out_sql_state, out_sql_code, out_failure);

    ASSOCIATE RESULT SET LOCATOR (result) WITH PROCEDURE READ_TRANSACTIONS;
    ALLOCATE cur CURSOR FOR RESULT SET result;

    FETCH cur INTO transaction_id ;
    INSERT INTO Z_OUTPUTS VALUES(transaction_id, out_sql_code, 
        out_sql_state, out_failure, CURRENT TIMESTAMP );
END;
```

Executing this block took 43 seconds, and the outputs are successfully written to Z_OUTPUTS:

```
[2018-01-08 10:31:36] completed in 43s 314ms
```

... whereas executing the same SQL statement without stored procedure works much much faster – between 1 and 2 seconds:

```
SELECT *
FROM TRANSACTION
WHERE COMPANY_ID = 52360839 AND TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'L'
ORDER BY TRANSACTION_STAMP DESC
LIMIT 500;

[2018-01-08 10:37:02] 500 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 2s 31ms
    (execution: 769ms, fetching: 1s 262ms)
```

Is there a way to improve the stored procedure to make it work fast? As I understand, the CURSOR creates a bottleneck, but it may be a wrong assumption.

**Bonus (quite weird thing)**
If in stored procedure we put constant LIMIT 500 instead of variable LIMIT in_TRANSACTION_LIMIT, then the stored procedure works very fast – executing the same SQL block took *43ms*. However, if we put LIMIT 1000 – 2 times larger, – then the execution of the block again takes very long – *31s 212ms*.

Comment: What Db2 version/platform?

Comment: The version is the following: DB2 11.1 Mod 2 Fix Pack 2, or Signature: 11.1.2.2, Build level: s1706091900

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the plan generated for the cursor in your SP is different from the one for the dynamically executed statement, because the optimizer cannot know the cardinality of the former (since you pass it as a stored procedure parameter). You can confirm that by comparing the two query plans.

To generate the query plan for the stored procedure package, first determine the package schema and name:

```
select 
  bschema, bname 
from 
  syscat.routinedep 
where 
  specificname = (
    select specificname from syscat.routines where routinename='READ_TRANSACTIONS'
  ) 
  and btype = 'K'
```

You can then use the `db2expn` utility to view the plan:

```
db2expln -d <your db> -t -c <package schema> -p <package name> -s 0
```

You may want to try and make the optimizer to regenerate the plan each time the procedure is invoked, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47613287/db2-luw-10-5-how-to-force-db2-stored-procedures-to-use-latest-stats-for-most-o/47638430#47638430) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214340/db2-conditional-where-clause/10219022#10219022).

If you expect the value of `in_TRANSACTION_LIMIT` to be within a certain range, you can pick some sensible frequent value and tell the optimizer to use it by adding, say, `OPTIMIZE FOR 300 ROWS` clause to your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Could not check the plan yet because it seems that DB2 client was not configured correctly to work with remote database, and getting errors when executing `db2expln`. I will update on the progress as soon as I manage to run the mentioned tool properly. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are comparing apples to oranges. Just test the READ_TRANSACTIONS using CALL statement. Your 43 second execution time is the end to end time for executing the internal SP, capturing the cursor output and then inserting into a second table. You should only be worried about how long your READ_TRANSACTIONS SP takes to execute. Given the simplicity of the query, I don't see any reason why READ_TRANSACTIONS SP would take considerably more time than running the statement directly. So just try executing that SP.